# Is there a link checker for SharePoint 2010?

Tags: hyperlink, tools

I'm looking for a program, feature or timerjob that checks links on SharePoint 2010 Publishing-Sites and Hyperlink-Lists if they are alive.

The Out-of-the-box link scanner of SharePoint checks only internal links. I need one that checks external links, too.

I tried non SharePoint link checkers, but they won't work with the SharePoint authentification. I found [SharePoint Link Checker](http://splinkchecker.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex and it sounds about right, but [seems to work only with SharePoint 2007](http://splinkchecker.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=216162).

Any tools I should check out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been trying the SEO IIS Extension from Microsoft and WinHTTrack, although my results are rather limited as we use Forms Based Authentication and neither of them do well with the pages under authentication.  That's where I really want to be able to do some reporting, but the options look to be limited.  Maybe I'll try my hand at hacking the CodePlex source but as a novice programmer, that will probably take me awhile.

I tried the SEO and it did not work for the site we have, which uses FBA.  WinHTTrack did not work either...however...I found that the Xenu link checked did a good job.

http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html#Download

It worked for my site, once I logged in and told it to keep cookies, then it was able to crawl all the parts of the site I needed to.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Mavention Scan Page for Broken Links](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/mavention-scan-page-broken-links/) feature.

[image: Mavention - Scan Page for Broken Links]

Comment: As I can see, this only checks for links on one page. I want to run a job, that scans all pages of selected site collections and report.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free tool at http://www.qipoint.com called SharePoint 2010 Broken Link Report Tool, scans site collections and builds csv reports, works well

Comment: We  require disclosure of any affiliation with  products or websites (even if they are free). Please see [May I promote products or websites I  am affiliated with here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) for guidelines.

Comment: Although you are affiliated with qipoint: Thanks for the info and welcome to SharePoint StackExchange, Oleg :)